# Why is "F" + "alse" not == "False"?

Tags: java, string-comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I cant understand why the declared variables is not the same.

ex code:

```
 String firstPart = "F";
 String whole = "False";
 String connected = firstPart + "alse";
 System.out.println(connected == whole);
```

Now this produce a boolean and I thought it would be 'true' BUT it is not, It comes out as false and I don't understand why.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: +1. A fair enough question if you don't know about `equals()`, although using "False" as the example confuses the issue (people may be marking you down thinking you want to comparing strings with booleans)

Comment: It is a common mistake.  But this question has probably been asked THOUSANDS of times before on SO.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time thou! It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you make `firstPart` final it will be the same object so `==` will be true.  Otherwise only the *contents* will be the same so you have to use `equals`

Comment: Strings in Java are immutable. So string a + string b will never == string c. Likely (string a + string b) will be allocated on the stack, while string c will be in the string pool.

Comment: The question is - if you're writing this kind of stuff in your code how will somebody else understand it?

Comment: @TejaswiRana This is a homework question to illustrate how the compiler works rather then to point out the many other errors with the syntax ;) Since i learned alot it was not a bad question in it self.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This

```
String connected = firstPart + "alse";
```

creates a *new* `String` object, with a new underlying char array and a new reference.

Consequently when you compare references (using '=='') you won't get a match. If you compare the actual object contents using `equals()` then you'll get the result you want (since `String.equals()` compares the contents of the underlying char arrays)

Comment: Just because others will see this, due to String interning, if you make the String assignments final, then (connected == whole) is indeed true.

Answer (score 20):

You are comparing references, not the values.

You'll need to use `equals`:

```
connected.equals(whole);
```

Answer (score 6):

You should compare strings using `equals()`. Like so:

`System.out.println(connected.equals(whole));`

Answer (score 1):

When you use "==" to compare the strings it means that you want to compare their reference values but not the values they have,  which in this case will return false.

you need to use `equals` method which will compare strings based upon the values they are holding..

Answer (score 1):

You should use .equals() method to compare string...

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, only PDTs can be checked with ==.  These are byte, short, int, long, float, double, boolean, char and of course, references.  As the two references you get are different objects, the result would be false.

For any ADT (or object), you have to make use of the equals() method.  All Java objects have them and you have to implement it for your own objects as well.  For the String object this has been done for you and the characters are compared for to test equality.

Answer (score 1):

Java ain't JavaScript - the comparison operators are different:

In java `==` means "are the two objects the *same* instance?", which corresponds to JavaScript's `===` operator.

In java `.equals()` for String means "are the characters the same", which corresponds to JavaScript's `==` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb: `==` compares object references, not object values. Overriding `equals` is the standard way to define equality amongst objects (`String` included since it is a class, not a primitive).

`firstPart`, `whole` and `connected` define a new `String` each, so their references are different even if `connected` and `whole` match the same `String` in the pool, because `==` will not contemplate value.